# Return last inserted ID/SERIAL values with CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

How do I get the last ID/SERIAL value inserted into a table? Is there a CockroachDB function similar to SQL Server’s `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There’s no function in CockroachDB for returning last inserted values. But you can use the [`RETURNING` clause](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/insert.html#insert-and-return-values) of the `INSERT` statement.

For example, this is how you’d use `RETURNING` to return an auto-generated [SERIAL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/serial.html) value:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL, name STRING); 
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('mike') RETURNING id;
```